# RED5 webcam capture failed to record sound

Tags: audio, video-capture, red5

I have been testing RED5's webcam capture feature. (version 0.9.1)

Videos captured via 'Simple Recorder' app have no sound and do not play over 'OFLA Demo' app. However videos captured via 'Publisher' demo app have sound and play well on 'OFLA Demo' app. When I download the videos with no sound and test with a desktop video player, I get 'unknown audio decoder' error.

Is this expected behaviour? If not, what would be causing this?

Jaepil

Comment: OK. I re-installed RED5 with r4156 revision from SVN trunk. This time videos captured with Simple Recorder worked well with oflaDemo app. And the missing audio decoder error is gone after i switched the video player to VLC.

Answer (score 0):

Reinstalled RED5 with r4156 revision from SVN trunk. This seems to have addressed the issue.